# Python - can i know if a printing occurred or not

Tags: python, command-line

I wrote a simple python script.
During the script i'm using

```
os.system ("diff file1 file2")
```

to check if two text files are similar or not.
I know the files are similar if nothing is being printed out.
In case nothing is being printed, i'd like to print out something
to the command line like "> the file are similar".

Any ideas?

Comment: first of all, could you include a bit more of your code so we can understand the context, secondly, you could read the output of the command, and then if its a difference display that to the user, if its nothing, tell the user its nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>>> import filecmp
>>> filecmp.cmp('file1.txt', 'file1.txt')
True
```

if `True` then just print message like both are similar
[filecmp](http://docs.python.org/library/filecmp.html)- A byte by byte efficient comparison it is

Comment: Thanks. So say if i wrote var = filecmp.cmp("file1.txt" , "file2.txt") than - print var it will print true if the file are similar?

Comment: I did not know this awesome module. Python really has "batteries included".
@oopsi: yes. Lookthe documentation for the module here: http://docs.python.org/library/filecmp.html

Answer (score 5):

something like this

```
import os
import copy
import subprocess

def command(command):
    env = copy.deepcopy(os.environ)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command,
                shell=True, env=env, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    result = proc.stdout.read()
    return result

ret = command("cmd /c diff file1 file2")
if ret == "":
    print "no result files are same"
else:
    print "results: \r\n %s" % ret
```

this is a more generic solution, for any type of command.