# How to check in makefile if python script outputs OK

Tags: python, makefile

I have a Python script, which checks my language translation files (in CSV format), if all the lines contain translations for all languages included in the CSV's first, header line. Script lists files/lines with missing translations. If no problem is found, it outputs OK.
**My question is following:**
how do I call the script from within the makefile and check, if the output was OK? If something else than OK was printed out by the script, I want the makefile to stop.

Any ideas?

Comment: subprocess is the way to go. or importing your other script and creating a class from it to use in your main code.

Answer (score 3):

`make` checks output status, not text which is output.  The simplest solution is to use `sys.exit(1)` in your python script if it doesn't check out OK.

for example:

```
targetfile: dependsonfile
      python pythonscript.py -o targetfile dependsonfile
```

Of course the actual syntax will depend critically on how `pythonscript.py` is meant to be called.

If your pythonscript just does a check, you can accomplish that as follows:

```
makethis: didcheck
    echo "made it" > makethis   

didcheck:  #dependencies here
    python -c 'import sys; sys.exit(1)'
    touch didcheck
```

then you call make as `make makethis`.

Comment: OK, that is great. How do I start the script and check for its exit status?

Comment: @Kokesh -- make checks the output status automatically -- you don't have to do anything with that.  See my update.

Comment: Thank you, it works great! My Makefile stops, if the script returns error + the lines marked as wrong are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If modifying the Python script so that it would indicate its result using an exit code is not possible, you can implement it in Make as follows (assuming you work on *nix):

```
check-i18n:
    @if [ `python your_script.py` = 'OK' ]; \
        then echo "good enough"; \
        else echo "too bad"; exit 1; \
    fi
```

Another option, less readable, but cross-platform (so it will work on Windows as well):

```
# String equality check.
eq = $(findstring $1,$(findstring $2,$1))

check-i18n:
    @$(if $(call eq,OK,$(shell python your_script.py)), \
        echo "good enough", \
        echo "too bad"; exit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

as my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920725/python-can-i-know-if-a-printing-occurred-or-not/11920772#11920772)

```
import os
import copy
import subprocess

def command(command):
    env = copy.deepcopy(os.environ)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command,
                shell=True, env=env, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    result = proc.stdout.read()
    return result

ret = command(YOUR COMMAND HERE)

if ret == "OK":
    print "yay"
else:
    print "oh no!: %s" % ret
```

if you showed your code i could better implement my answer into it.